# How come when I don't export an interface used in a Component, I don't get any errors?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm following a [basic angular2 tutorial](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/03/25/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-1-your-first-component/) that constructs a Component. The Component uses the following interface:

```
// app/person.ts

export interface Person {
    name: string;
    weight: number;
    height: number;
}
```

I decided to delete the `export` keyword in front of the `Person` interface to see what happens. I didn't get any errors, and the app worked normally.  Why is that? (Yes, I saved the file--the development environment employs automatic reloading.) If I delete the export keyword in front of any class in the app, I get errors.

Thanks.

```
// app/people.service.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person'
import { PeopleService } from './people.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'people-list',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of people">
      {{ person.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
export class PeopleListComponent {
/*
  people: Person[] = [
    {name: 'Luke Skywalker', height: 70, weight: 140},
    {name: 'Darth Vader', height: 80, weight: 160},
    {name: 'Hans Solo', height: 85, weight: 170},
  ];
*/
  people: Person[] = []

  constructor(private _peopleService: PeopleService) {
    this.people = _peopleService.getAll();
  }


}
```

Comment: Are you using a typescript enabled IDE - that gives you typescript errors? As I would expect a Typescript error here if you try to import Person somewhere else. The fact that your app still works is because an Interface isn't actually used runtime (in the compiled code).

Comment: @MikeOne: Thanks for taking a look.  Nope, I'm using Vim. _Interface isn't actually used runtime_ Yeah, I read about that.  TypeScript still has to be instructed as to what it should and shouldn't do, and I thought you had to export something for TypeScript to allow you to import it--it shouldn't be up to the IDE to enforce TypeScript rules, should it?

Comment: How exactly is your `Component` using this `Person` interface? Please add the code.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, All the code is at the link, but I'll post it anyways.

Comment: When I try to compile something like that I get `Module 'module/file"' has no exported member 'Person'`. If you try to compile it using `tsc` you still don't get an error?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I'm too new to know what `tsc` is.  As far as I know I'm not compiling anything.  I hit Save, and then everything reloads in the browser, so my .ts files must be compiled into .js files automatically.

Comment: `tsc` is the typescript compiler. your build tools might not work as expected, and it might not compile your ts source when you save a file. check what you get when you use `tsc` yourself then you'll know

Comment: @NitzanTomer, Hmm...If I delete the entire content of my `person.ts` file, my app still works perfectly.  This time I did notice that the terminal window where I did `$ npm start` had an error scroll by, which included the line: _app/person.ts' is not a module_.  If I stop the server in the `$ npm start` window and restart it by doing  `$ npm start` again, the server crashes with the message: _NPM ERR!! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"_.  When I paste the content back into person.ts,`$ npm start` works again.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: In any case, I'm not going to worry about it anymore.  I'm going to forge ahead with the tutorial, and later I'll figure out how to set up a better development environment.  This clearly seems like a development environment problem and not some quirk in angular2/typescript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you're going to work with typescript, I suggest that you stop with the angular part, and get to know ts a bit better, including the build process.